# in Openshift environment, how to access a database in a different application?

Tags: php, mysql, openshift, remote-access

I have been trying to access a mysql in a jboss eap application from a wordpress application in Openshift environment. I followed [this blog post](https://blog.openshift.com/sharing-database-across-applications/) on this subject and prepared a php file on the wordpress server with $dbhost, $dbuser, $password point to the database in my jbosseap app. Unfortunately, it did not work. Each time I got a "no route to host" error. However, if I point the database to that in the wordpress app, i.e. local database, it worked perfectly.

I am wondering if there must be additional step(s) to execute when the php script and the database are in different Openshift applications?

Comment: Is the JBoss EAP application a scaled application, or a single gear? In other words is the MySQL server running on a separate gear in the JBoss application?

Answer (score 0):

I've ha same problem following this guide https://blog.openshift.com/sharing-database-across-applications/,

the solution is writen even there:

> Step 1: Create an application with a database

We will create a **scalable** PHP application using a MySQL database cartridge. In non-scalable applications, the database will be installed in the same
gear as the application. In this case we want the database to be accessible from other gears. **So creating a scalable application ensures that the database runs in its own gear that can be accessed from other gears**.

Here 
http://www.hfaber.com/post/135256827109/openshift-sharing-database-across-applications

Answer (score 0):

After talking to some people in Redhat, I concluded that it is not possible to share database accesses between different applications in Openshift environment. You may see some technical documents which show how to do it, but that is for Openshift/Redhat internet environments, not for regular customers of Openshift.
At the end, I used webservices to provide sharing of DB accesses between applications.

The investigation was in August 2015. Hope it will or has changed