# How to remotely connect to OpenShift MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I've a `Tomcat 7` application running on `Openshift` server, say `myapp`.
I've also installed `MySQL 5.5` cartridge and got the username and password say `myUsername` and `myPassword` respectively.

I tried to remotely connect to the database by writing a simple PHP script from my php localhost.

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('127.8.217.2:3306', 'myUsername', 'myPassword');

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully';

mysql_select_db('myapp',$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
```

but the output shows

`Could not connect: Access denied for user 'myUsername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I don't know what i am missing.

Now the question part.

1) Is it possible to remotely connect to the `OpenShift MySQL database` using PHP from either `localhost` or some other server ?  If yes, How ?

If there's any question, shoot it into the comments.

EDIT

I've looked at `port-forwarding` with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749599/openshift-how-to-remote-access-mysql) thread. but that's not i want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Openshift: How to remote access MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749599/openshift-how-to-remote-access-mysql)

Comment: though I don't really understand why do you even want to connect locally from php. You have an application with Tomcat 7 running on openshift, so what's the deal with local PHP? Allowing remote DB access for no real reason is usually not a very good idea.

Comment: @eis I really don't want to connect to the database from the localhost, but from a `PHP` script hosted in a different server.

Comment: but why? Why not just have an REST API or similar with your JBoss application and connect to that, like is usually done? Connecting directly to the database remotely is a security risk.

Comment: @eis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523566/access-remote-mysql-serveropenshift-via-codeigniter (this sounds similar to my problem, but it's an unanswered question).

Comment: @eis The problem is I've an application that has a `REST API` written in `Java` and an admin panel written in `PHP`. I think both the `PHP` and `Java` can't work on the same OpenShift server. So that's why we hosted the adminp panel on a different `PHP` server. Now that server needs to access the data that exists in the `OpenShift` server.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation as having a need for a both Java and PHP application needing to connect to same server, your options are either

1) doing port forwarding or connecting through SSH, both explained in [this link I offered as a duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749599/openshift-how-to-remote-access-mysql), or

2) Trying something [explained here](https://blog.openshift.com/sharing-database-across-applications/) and [here](http://www.hfaber.com/post/135256827109/openshift-sharing-database-across-applications) to create a shared database using a scalable application - however, people in other similar threads, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813140/in-openshift-environment-how-to-access-a-database-in-a-different-application), have claimed that it is "for Openshift/Redhat internet environments, not for regular customers of Openshift" ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34334137/365237)). Don't know if it is so, but at least if you go this way, you should test from another openshift gear, not from local computer.